# Is there any method to remove a useless contract from the blockchain just like "selfdestruct" in ETH?

Tags: smart-contract

As I know, in ETH, when a contract would be useless, it could be destroyed by using the "selfdestruct" action.
So, is there any same method to remove a useless contract from the eos blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [v1.3.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.3.0), it is now possible to delete the smart contract from an account using the `--clear` flag (`$ cleos set contract <account> --clear`)

Comment: That would be very great

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a selfdestruct action, but there is a setcode action. A contract can use that to destroy itself like in [this example](https://gist.github.com/tbfleming/253e84d14e13e713917aac68e737d48f).

Comment: thanks for your help man, but this method is using dead code to cover the contract byte, right ?   is it too heavy for a contract developer to do that ?

Comment: Correct. It's hard to judge too heavy right now until the ram market is active.